# How to drop item into drop area whenever both index match?

Tags: unity

so I want to add some mechanics when on my inventory, whenever the item index `in this case index of scriptableobject` and drop area index match the item can drop on that area

for that, I've actually checked like this

```
 if ((DragAndDropItem.draggedItem.itemDesc.indexAyat == _CheckInvent.instance.currIndex))
        {
            ...
        }
```

when the `index of Scriptableobject` matches with `index of drop area` then do the thing, but it's not working I don't know why, what I want here I can drop the item when both of index match.

### Here the full script

- DragnDropCell.cs

```cs
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData data)
    {
        if (DragAndDropItem.icon != null)
        {
            DragAndDropItem item = DragAndDropItem.draggedItem;
            DragAndDropCell sourceCell = DragAndDropItem.sourceCell;
            if (DragAndDropItem.icon.activeSelf == true)                    // If icon inactive do not need to drop item into cell
            {
                if ((item != null) && (sourceCell != this))
                {
                    DropEventDescriptor desc = new DropEventDescriptor();
                    switch (cellType)                                       // Check this cell's type
                    {
                        case CellType.Swap:                                 // Item in destination cell can be swapped
                            UpdateMyItem();
                            switch (sourceCell.cellType)
                            {
                                case CellType.Swap:                         // Item in source cell can be swapped
                                    // Fill event descriptor
                                    desc.item = item;
                                    desc.sourceCell = sourceCell;
                                    desc.destinationCell = this;
                                    SendRequest(desc);                      // Send drop request
                                    StartCoroutine(NotifyOnDragEnd(desc));  // Send notification after drop will be finished
                                    if (desc.permission == true)            // If drop permitted by application
                                    {
                                        if (myDadItem != null)            // If destination cell has item
                                        {
                                            // Fill event descriptor
                                            DropEventDescriptor descAutoswap = new DropEventDescriptor();
                                            descAutoswap.item = myDadItem;
                                            descAutoswap.sourceCell = this;
                                            descAutoswap.destinationCell = sourceCell;
                                            SendRequest(descAutoswap);                      // Send drop request
                                            StartCoroutine(NotifyOnDragEnd(descAutoswap));  // Send notification after drop will be finished
                                            if (descAutoswap.permission == true)            // If drop permitted by application
                                            {
                                                SwapItems(sourceCell, this);                // Swap items between cells
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                PlaceItem(item);            // Delete old item and place dropped item into this cell
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            PlaceItem(item);                // Place dropped item into this empty cell
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:                                    // Item in source cell can not be swapped
                                    // Fill event descriptor
                                    desc.item = item;
                                    desc.sourceCell = sourceCell;
                                    desc.destinationCell = this;
                                    SendRequest(desc);                      // Send drop request
                                    StartCoroutine(NotifyOnDragEnd(desc));  // Send notification after drop will be finished
                                    if (desc.permission == true)            // If drop permitted by application
                                    {
                                        PlaceItem(item);                    // Place dropped item into this cell
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case CellType.DropOnly:                             // Item only can be dropped into destination cell
                                                                            // Fill event descriptor

                            desc.item = item;
                            desc.sourceCell = sourceCell;
                            desc.destinationCell = this;
                            SendRequest(desc);                              // Send drop request
                            StartCoroutine(NotifyOnDragEnd(desc));          // Send notification after drop will be finished
                            if (desc.permission == true)                    // If drop permitted by application
                            {
                                PlaceItem(item);                            // Place dropped item in this cell
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (item != null)
            {
                if (item.GetComponentInParent<DragAndDropCell>() == null)   // If item have no cell after drop
                {
                    Destroy(item.gameObject);                               // Destroy it
                }
            }
            UpdateMyItem();
            UpdateBackgroundState();
            sourceCell.UpdateMyItem();
            sourceCell.UpdateBackgroundState();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Put item into this cell.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Item.</param>
    private void PlaceItem(DragAndDropItem item)
    {
        if ((DragAndDropItem.draggedItem.itemDesc.indexAyat == _CheckInvent.instance.currIndex))
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                DestroyItem();                                              // Remove current item from this cell
                myDadItem = null;
                DragAndDropCell cell = item.GetComponentInParent<DragAndDropCell>();
                if (cell != null)
                {
                    if (cell.unlimitedSource == true)
                    {
                        string itemName = item.name;
                        item = Instantiate(item);                               // Clone item from source cell
                        item.name = itemName;
                        //item.myImage.sprite = item.itemDesc.imageAyat;
                    }
                }
                item.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
                item.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
                item.MakeRaycast(true);
                myDadItem = item;
                myDadItem.myImage.sprite = item.itemDesc.imageAyat;
                myDadItem.myImage.raycastTarget = false;
            }
            UpdateBackgroundState();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Really struggling to follow your problem statement. Can you please try rephrasing, and also include what you mean by "It doesn't work". What happens? Do you get an error? What is it?

Comment: @Basic sorry I forgot to add that, the point is I want to have the condition when both indexes match so the item can be dropped on the cell or drop area.